# question regarding Echoclient program

Tags: java

I am always getting the message Don't know about host: taranis. while running echoclient program. here is the program below

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class EchoClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Socket echoSocket = null;
        PrintWriter out = null;
        BufferedReader in = null;

        try {
            echoSocket = new Socket("taranis",3218);
            out = new PrintWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                        echoSocket.getInputStream()));
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.err.println("Don't know about host: taranis.");
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for "
                               + "the connection to: taranis.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

    BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(
                                   new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String userInput;

    while ((userInput = stdIn.readLine()) != null) {
        out.println(userInput);
        System.out.println("echo: " + in.readLine());
    }

    out.close();
    in.close();
    stdIn.close();
    echoSocket.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Who is taranis? do you have a computer with that name in your network?

Comment: Erm, well ... it means there's no such host as "taranis". You need to use a valid hostname.

Comment: FYI: This code seems to be from here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a valid host name, or a valid IP of your server (assuming you have one) when you initialize your [socket](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html) (`new Socket("taranis",3218)` ). It is great to take those tutorials (as pointed by **icktoofay**), but especially when it comes to networking, you have to make sure you have the matching application running on the other side, and that the parameters match it. IP and port usually change from machine to machine and from application to application.